# PyCharm type hinting enum iteration

Tags: python, enums, pycharm, type-hinting

Python's enum class supports iteration, but PyCharm has trouble figuring this out.

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 0
    BLUE = 1

for color in Color:
    # Warning: Expected 'collections.Iterable', got 'Type[Color]' instead
    print(color)
```

Though the method `EnumMeta.__iter__` exists, PyCharm has trouble figuring this out.

I don't mind manually adding type hinting to work around the problem, I'm just not sure what and where.

Comment: Pycharm doesn't seem to give any warnings for me, version is 2017.2.4.

Comment: I've got the same version. Maybe you have a different `Code compatibility inspection` setting? Mine is checked for 2.7 and 3.6.

Comment: I've enabled it and still don't get that warning, my type checking seems to be working fine (`for color in 10:` will show a warning).

Comment: Are you using enum34 backport?

Comment: pycharm 2017.3.3 has the same issue

Comment: It's a bug in PyCharm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe it's not cleanest solution, but following works for me:

```py
from enum import Enum
import typing

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 0
    BLUE = 1

Color = Color  # type: typing.Union[typing.Type[Color], typing.Iterable]
```

PyCharm [supports](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html) type hinting using format defined in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) (for Python versions lower than 3.5 in the form of comments, for 3.5 and higher in form of annotations).

Important note here is that on Python version lower than 3.5, importing `typing` module should be guarded in some way (PyCharm recognizes this import as valid, even without having `typing` module installed in site packages, however when code is run `ImportError` occurs).

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that I used in PyCharm was through use of `__members__` with `.items()`

```py
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 0
    BLUE = 1

for name, color in Color.__members__.items():
    print(name, color)
```

Returning:

```
('RED', <Color.RED: 0>)
('BLUE', <Color.BLUE: 1>)
```

See the following link for reference:

https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/enum.html#iteration